# Overriding the Telerik RadGrid AddNewRecordButton functionality to redirect the user to a new page rather than add a new insert record row to the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid

Previously when my RadGrid was not a batch edit grid I was able to use the grid's AddNewRecord button to redirect the user to another page with the following code:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "InitInsert")
    {
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl + "?ProductID=" + this.ProductId);
    }
}
```

After I made my grid a batch edit grid the Add New Button doesn't go into the ItemCommand event anymore and instead tries adding an inline insert record row to the grid. Is there anyway I can still use this button and override its functionality to still redirect the user?

Comment: Is there a save button on the grid? If so, does it redirect if you click save after entering a record? My guess is the batch edit mode doesn't actually call a postback until you click save. If that's the case, I would try to figure out a way to still make the Add New button cause a postback in batch mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've tested this and confirmed what I suspected in the comments. When `EditMode="Batch"`, the "Add New Record" button, along with others, no longer cause a postback. You can override this by removing the JavaScript of the `OnClientClick` in the `RadGrid1_ItemCreated` like so:

Add this to your `RadGrid1` attributes:

```
OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"
```

Code behind (note: there is actually a `Button` AND a `LinkButton`):

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.CommandItem) {
        //This is the icon with the plus (+) sign unless you've changed the icon
        Button iconButton = e.Item.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton");
        if (iconButton != null) {
            iconButton.OnClientClick = "";
        }
        //This is the words "Add New Record" or whatever you've called it
        LinkButton wordButton = e.Item.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
        if (wordButton != null) {
            wordButton.OnClientClick = "";
        }
    }
}
```

This should allow the postback to happen and the code you posted should be able to run.